# Прокрутка до нужной даты android java

Tags: java, android

Нашел такой компонент, но не могу понять как при открытии сделать так чтобы была показана выбранная дата, сейчас показывает только дату с которой всё начинается.
https://github.com/101Loop/DatePickerTimeline

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему после инициализации начальной даты

```
DatePickerTimeline datePickerTimeline = findViewById(R.id.dateTimeline);
datePickerTimeline.setInitialDate(2019, 10, 12);
```

Что бы установить отметку на нужной дате необходимо сделать вызов

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 5); // устанавливаем нужную дату
datePickerTimeline.setActiveDate(date); // активируем эту дату в календаре
```

Comment: нужно именно чтобы этот recyclerview прокрутился до этой даты